# Accurately isolate force cell

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, mosfet, sensor, switches

I am using the circuit below, which is comprised of 4 Tekscan Flexiforce sensors (https://www.tekscan.com/products-solutions/force-sensors/a301). In the circuit below, the sensors are Rs0, Rs1, Rs2, and Rs3.

The first op-amp is to dynamically control the force range of the sensors and output a signal from Vref (0.5 volts using the voltage divider 9k and 1k) to 5V.

The second op-amp subtracts the offset (Vref) and amplifies to 0-5V.

I also have MOSFET's attached to each sensor to control which one is active. I built this circuit, but noticed that the sensors that are pulled LOW using the MOSFET are still introducing some signal in the output. Basically, when I press the sensors that are supposed to be inactive, they are still outputting a small signal.

I am assuming a MOSFET was not the right choice, and there are better switch devices to pull the sensors to GND harder. What other kind of devices should I include to better isolate each force cell? Any other thoughts would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those 2N7000 are a reasonable choice, but the specified leakage current (1 uA at room temperature) would cause the effects you observe. Do you have a way to measure if in fact the FETs are leaking that much ?

In any case, you can make the circuit insensitive to FET leakage by adding additional FETs between the drain of each FET and the opamp's non-inverting ('+') input. When you switch off each sensor (e.g. M1), turn on the corresponding new FET also. The new FETs should have drain = '+' input; source = junction of sensor and existing FETs.

This works because the opamp creates a 'virtual ground' at its '-' input. By switching the bottom node of each sensor to the '+' input, the unused sensor will have nearly zero V across it and therefore will not affect the behavior of the circuit. The leakage in the additional FETs will have a negligible effect on anything else.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that your reference voltage at the + input of the op amp needs to be extremely stable, and generating it as you do is asking for trouble. Power supply noise and variation need to be accounted for.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thanks for the info. Would you suggest using a reference diode? I'm using one currently for an my Arduino ADC.

Comment: @tabchas - It all depends on your power supply. How quiet is it, and how stable? It's your call.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Well this is a prototype (but would still like to get it as stable and accurate as possible) so I'm using my Arduino's power supply which is powered over USB. Any suggestions on additional components to make the power supply more stable? I currently have 0.1uF cap on the power rails as well.

Comment: @jp314, Clever idea. I have a multimeter so I can measure the leakage current on the FETs. I'll definitely test out your idea. Thanks!

Comment: Actually your whole opamp circuit is a little strange. How 'perfect' you need to be depends on the accuracy you are trying to achieve. Normally R10 would be 100k also to make OP3 a proper difference amplifier; then VOUT2 would be  VREF*rf/rs. Also best to add 1k in series with R9 (make it 101k) to match impedance from R1//R2.

Comment: @tabchas - The obvious place to start is a cap across R2. However, you may find the nonlinearities in the sensor are more important than power supply issues. You'll just have to pay attention to what you're doing.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast ok thanks for the tip. What value cap should I use across R2? Any other suggestions to look into?

Comment: @jp314 Got it. I'll look into this a bit more and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @tabchas - Try something like 1 uF, and not an aluminum electrolytic. Tantalum or ceramic.

Comment: If you are powering from USB, you'll need better filtering than that. Use 0.1 uF ceramic and 47 uF electrolytic.

Comment: @jp314 I built your idea on CircuitLab, but still get voltage across the transistors that are supposed to have very little voltage across it. Here is a picture with the voltage across each resistor (shown on the left and marked from Node1-Node4): http://i.imgur.com/EJVJctY.png

Comment: That appears correct to me. Node2-4 are at 504 mV which is 4 mv different from 500 mV -- caused by the offset of the amplifier. Node 1 is at 7 uV which is 500mV*RDSON/200k; with RDSON=3ohm this is about correct. You have a small error caused by the three 4 mV/10M, but this is similar to the errors you have because of the two opamp's offsets.

Comment: @jp314 Sweet. I also tried measuring the current through the transistors, but don't think I could detect any current leaking through the transistors that are turned LOW. Any thoughts? I was measuring from the end of one sensor to the drain of the transistor

Comment: If you don't have a good DMM, you won't be able to measure 1u A leakages. Put the DMM in voltage mode and measure across the sensors - if the FETs are not leaking much, it should be low (should be < 4 mV if you add the 4 FETs.). How much crosstalk do you actually see -- if it's < few %, then you are probably at the limit of this topology. The solution then is to use 4*OA1, and use the FETs to switch the appropriate one to OA3.

Comment: @jp314 I tired the additional FET idea, but still getting the same fluctuations in signal. Is there a better choice than FETs? I feel there must be a better solution than 4*OA1's. The crosstalk is definitely significant - my Arduino ADC sees weird fluctuations in signal (like its at least +-0.2-0.5 volts) as I press and release the sensors that are supposed to be inactive. The voltage across the inactive sensors are < 4mV, but my DMM sometimes adjusts and shows weird spikes.

Comment: FETs are the only realistic choice -- you could use relays, but that's large. 

Are you sure you are not picking up AC noise/interference ? How long are the wires to the sensors ?

Comment: @jp314 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33194/discussion-between-tabchas-and-jp314).